# Animate something that doesn't exist on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-animate

Ajax sets up a scenario and jQuery then plays it out.  The element does not exist before the page is loaded. I need a way to Animate something that was dynamically added to the page.

Something like:

```
$(document).on("animate", "div", function (){});
```

Does anything like this exist?

Okay, there seems to be some confusion, I am using queue() this isn't the issue creating it or doing something after I have the ajax return.  After the Ajax the program builds and inserts imgs with specific IDs into the page.  I need to reload the dom or something so that I can then animate the objects that were inserted into the page.

I have tested the animated on JSfiddle and they work fine, so my only assumption is that because these objects are not part of the initial dom they will not animate and thus I need the DOM to reload.

Comment: So animate it when you create it. What problem are you facing?

Comment: It doesn't animate at all actually. This works http://jsfiddle.net/emFpw/3/ so my assumption is that because the elements are created after the page the DOM needs to reload.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is animate it with the proper function, like:

```
$("#nonexistent-element").animate({
  right: '10%'
});
```

and it will animate once #nonexistent-element exists, regardless of whether it existed at page load. You only need to use on() when you want to bind an event to an element that does not exist on page load.

Working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/emFpw/26/

Comment: I had something nearly identical to that and it wouldn't run at all.  I rebuilt it all to just have pet-left on the page before its loaded and then the image is placed inside it.  I will however try this again.

Answer (score -1):

When the content is loaded via Ajax, we need to bind the events for them to work or we can use the live/on methods of jQuery which will bind the events to either parent/document depending on what we want.

Either of the two techniques ie binding when the content is loaded or using live/on should result in the event being triggered.

For ex: Once the content in inserted we can do as suggested by **Lrdwhyt** in the above answer. 
Or we bind the element before its loaded like

```
$("#non-existing-elem").live("click",function(){
     $(this).animate({right:'10'});
})
```